# NodeJS Download and Upload In-Memory Stream Asynchronously

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, axios

**Question**
How do you asynchronously download and (resumable/multi-part) upload large MP4 files purely through Streams in NodeJS (without using filesystem)?

**Scenario**
I'm writing a class file that is concerned with streaming downloads from a URL to Google Drive or Dropbox purely through memory.

***The file size is known prior to the download and upload.*

**Visual**

```
==============
      ^(5%)  ^(10%)
Downloader

      ==============
            ^(5%)  ^(10%)
       Uploader
```

**Requirements**

1. Transfer through Memory Streams (without storing anything on the filesystem)
2. The uploads should be multi-part resumable and may range anywhere from 5 Mb to > 20 Gb.
3. If a download or upload fails, there should be a set number of retries.

**Curiosities**

1. Is a duplex stream (e.g. passthrough) the correct way of doing this?
2. How do you convey `Content-Length` within an asynchronous method as visualized above?

**Pseudo Code**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const stream = require('stream');
const passtrough = new stream.PassThrough();

let sample = VideoAPI.get() // pass id
//sample.url // url located here
//sample.size // size is known prior to download or upload
//sample.contentType // content-type is known prior to download

//Download sample via Axios
axios.get(sample.url, {
    responseType: "stream"
}).then((response) => {
    //TODO: Pipe to Google Drive
    console.log('response', response)
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
})
```

**Research**

1. [Upload to Google Drive w/ Passthrough Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57365997/node-js-get-zip-from-a-url-and-upload-to-google-drive)
2. [Resumable upload](https://gist.github.com/dam1/f77fcbea52ca9124ff50f3598d280710)
3. [Webshot to Google Drive without Intermediate File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901838/webshot-to-google-drive-without-storing-intermediate-file-using-buffers-or-stre)

Comment: Whats the problem ? With what are you struggeling ?

Comment: @Marc I'm mostly confused how to communicate correctly Content-Length in a multi-part upload within an asynchronously piped stream.

Comment: The asynchron approach does not work here. You have to download all files first, manipulate the "file" or in memory stream, calcualte total body length & upload your files again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need sth like this :

```
request.get(sourceUrl).pipe(request.post(targetUrl))
```

In this scheme, the data will flow from *sourceUrl* to *targetUrl* but will not need to be saved in a temporary file on the server.

For clarification visit [request#streaming](https://github.com/request/request#streaming)

Comment: I appreciate the elegance of this.  I notice I'm curious about how to handle multi-part or resumable uploads with a file greater than 1 GB to the target URL with consideration around how the headers, especially `Content-Length` are communicated within the upload.  Thank you for sharing.

Comment: I've come across this finding: 
"Request can also pipe to itself. When doing so, content-type and content-length are preserved in the PUT headers."

This seems like it may be on the right track in satisfying the curiosity above but I am not certain and will test.

Comment: I implemented this with the `request-progress` library and it is working like a charm.  Thank you for sharing your insights, friend.

Comment: @pixelbobby I'm happy to hear that. We are here to help each other. good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const formData = new FormData();

axios.get(sample.url, {
    responseType: "stream"
}).then((response) => {
    //TODO: Pipe to Google Drive
    // you can directly put the response stream onto the formData object.
    formData.append('files', response.data);
    return axios.post(googleURL,{headers:{...formData.getheaders()}, data: formData});
.then((response)=>{
//response from google
console.log(response.data);
})
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
})

//N.B. The response.data steam will be appended to the formData object, this is all done in memory. Make sure the responseType is set to stream.
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.